# Swift: Little confused on why protocols are useful in this situation

Tags: swift, protocols

I came across this   example here

```
 protocol Barker {
    func bark()
}

class GermanShephard: Barker {
    func bark() {
        print("Bark")
    }
}

class BelgianMalinois: Barker {
    func bark() {
        print("Bark!")
    }
}

let dog = BelgianMalinois()
dog.bark()
```

I know how it works. However, I don't know what the benefit of doing this. You can remove the protocol and still get the same result. Any explanation will be useful. I know a delegate with protocols are useful for sending a message from one object to another. This is helpful because any object can inherit a delegate. So that way libraries like UITableView don't have to reference your object to send a message to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol isn't needed in your simple example. But let's expand your example:

```
func handleBarkingDog(_ barker: Barker) {
    barker.bark()
}

let dog1 = BelgianMalinois()
let dog2 = GermanShephard()

handleBarkingDog(dog1)
handleBarkingDog(dog2)

var barker: Barker = dog1
barker = dog2
```

Without the protocol (or a base class), you wouldn't be able to pass references to the two different types of dogs to a common method or assign them to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Since the method has a parameter type Barker it can take any object that conforms to the protocol. Or if you create a type barker it can be assigned  an object that conforms to protocol as well. Makes a lot more sense and seems more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it either.  If I wanted to show a protocol in action, I'd replace the last two code lines with something like:

```
func tease(_ barker: Barker) {
    barker.bark()
}

tease(GermanShephard())
tease(BelgianMalinois())
```

Answer (score -1):

Protocols can be used to define some common features. Consider the following example.

```
protocol Walker {
    func walk()
}

class Dog: Walker {
    func walk() {
        print("Walk with four legs")
    }
}

class Human: Walker {
    func walk() {
        print("Walk with two legs")
    }
}

let spitz = Dog()
spitz.walk() // prints "Walks with four legs"

let person = Human()
human.walk() // prints "Walks with two legs"
```

In the above example, bpth Dog and Human conforms to protocol Walker, which means both dog and human have feature to walk. However the implementation could be different.

Comment: Your answer does not clarify why having the protocol is useful. In your answer there is no reason at all for the protocol.